# VB.Net Checking if DataSet has rows or not

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
 Private Function Gelobee() As DataSet
    Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CMP.accdb"
    connection.Open()
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT IDDesc FROM [ItemDesc] WHERE IDPartNo = '" & PartNoTxt.Text & "';", connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "FilteredDesc")
    connection.Dispose()
    connection = Nothing
    If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    If ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 Then
            DescTxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
        Else
            DescTxt.Text = "No Description"
        End If
    End If

    Return ds
End Function
```

Hi, I'm trying to check if the data set has rows. But it's giving me error at "ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0". Anything wrong with my code? I tried to search all over the net but I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It says "Error 1 Value of type 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'."

Comment: If I understand the title right.. a dataset don't have rows. It is a "Set of DataTables".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VB.NET syntax to access an indexer should be with parentheses...

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is you have used "[]" in VB.net instead of "()"

Your code should be corrected as

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
```